# Function with dictionary that takes a string as input and counts the number of times each letter appears wont print

Tags: python

I made a function that I believed would take a string and return how many times each letter occurs in the phrase "I love Python", but when I run my code:

```
def countletters(s):
    s = s.lower()
    letters = {'I' :0, 'l':0, 'o':0, 'v':0, 'e':0, 'P':0, 'y':0, 't':0, 'h':0, 'o':0, 'n':0}
    for char in s:
        if char in letters:
            letters[char]+=1
    return letters

def printResults(result_dict):
    print
```

all the output window shows is my input and no output leading me to believe my print method is incorrect, but is something else incorrect with my code?

Comment: You never call `countletters`.

Comment: You aren't printing anything. Note how you never call `countletters`.

Comment: Just do `print(countletters('I love Python'))`

Comment: even after doing print(countletters('I love Python')) I still get the input

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few errors in your code:

```
def countletters(s):
s = s.lower()
```

Firstly, the line `s = s.lower()` should be indented.

Secondly, in the dictionary, the key `"I"` should be changed to "i", due to the fact that the string `s` has been changed to all lowercase.

Also, in the rest of your code, there are numerous mistakes:
    def printResults(result_dict):
    print

Mistake 1: result_dict

You have set result_dict as a parameter for the `printResults` function. This should be used. Otherwise, it is wasted.

Mistake 2: Indentation

You should indent your code inside the `printResults` function with a tab or four spaces.

Mistake 3: Print

The `print` function requires brackets `()` in order to tell Python what to print.

Mistake 4: Also print

You are not printing anything with that print function. Maybe change it to print the result of the `countletters` function using `print(result_dict)`.

Also, you should run `printResults` and use what `countletters` returns as a parameter. For example:

```
printResults(countletters("I love python"))
```

Mistake 5: Functions

In order to use the code inside the functions, you need to call them. For example:

```
countletters("I love python")
```

EDIT: Barmar has fixed up your indentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your example string is

**Step 1:**

`s = 'i love python'`

And your function is:

```
def countletters(s):
    s = s.lower()
    letters = {'i' :0, 'l':0, 'o':0, 'v':0, 'e':0, 'p':0, 'y':0, 't':0, 'h':0, 'o':0, 'n':0}
    for char in s:
        if char in letters:
            letters[char]+=1
    return letters
```

**Step 2:**

Result :

`print(countletters(s))`

`>>> {'i': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 2, 'v': 1, 'e': 1, 'p': 1, 'y': 1, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'n': 1}`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I've used r studio and java mainly and for some reason python seems so foreign sometimes I forget such essential things.

Comment: @CharlesAdams Welcome